# SQL Teradata TOP and DISTINCT

Tags: sql, teradata, distinct

I'm trying to write a nested TOP + DISTINCT query in Teradata SQL. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5
    *
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT k_name.KUNDE_NAME1
     FROM DB_DWH_MART_AKM_PLT.VW_F_EVENT f_ev
     INNER JOIN DBX_DWH_SBX_AKM_PRD.TB_KUNDE_EKP_NAME_AKTUELL k_name ON f_ev.AUFTRAGGEBER_EKP = k_name.EKP
     WHERE f_ev.PROCESS_NO = 1075)
```

I get an error:

> Expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier... between ) and ;".

I don't know what I did wrong.

The `DISTINCT` query would execute correctly on its own.

Comment: Maybe you need to give an alias for the subquery like  `... FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT .... ) AS a`

Comment: @KotaMori you were right! thank you!

Comment: Is the _derived table_ (the subquery) even needed? (I have never used Teradata, so I don't know.)

Comment: @jarlh unfortunately, Teradata wont allow you to use DISTINCT TOP...

Comment: You do realize this will not return consistent results?

Comment: @Andrew Why and how?

Comment: With no order by, the result is non-deterministic.  Run it multiple times, and you'll almost certainly get different results.

Comment: @Andrew thanks, thats good to know! In this example I just used it to reduce the runtime, the "order"/consistency is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `group by`?

```
SELECT TOP 5 k_name.KUNDE_NAME1
FROM DB_DWH_MART_AKM_PLT.VW_F_EVENT f_ev
INNER JOIN DBX_DWH_SBX_AKM_PRD.TB_KUNDE_EKP_NAME_AKTUELL k_name ON f_ev.AUFTRAGGEBER_EKP = k_name.EKP
WHERE f_ev.PROCESS_NO = 1075
GROUP BY k_name.KUNDE_NAME1 --instead of using distinct
ORDER BY k_name.KUNDE_NAME1; --remove or modify as needed
```

Comment: Would probably work as well. Is there a runtime difference?

Comment: Both DISTINCT and GROUP BY might get the same plan (optimization is based on data demographics)